# Как в C# в коде программы определять свойства PictureBOX?

Tags: c#

Нужно, чтобы в коде программы определялось значение Location: X и Y и Size: Width и Height для дальнейшего их использования в программе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;
int width = pictureBox1.Size.Width;
int height = pictureBox1.Size.Height;
```

А вопрос в чём заключается?

Comment: спасибо. это мне и надо было.

Comment: Раз уж на то пошло, то подскажите, пожалуйста: как узнать, какое изображение было загружено из ресурсов в PictureBox?

Comment: Так же, как загружали — через свойство Image ;).

Comment: В переменную какого типа?